# Genserver state change during handle_info or handle_call

Tags: elixir, gen-server

Suppose I have a simple genserver that mantains a simple :queue as it's state. Items are continually being added with handle_cast. Every 5 seconds I process the queue with Process.send_after. That call gets handled with a call back to handle_info with the current state.  The queue gets processed and emptied then a new empty queue is applied as the current state of the genserver.

My question is this: 
What happens when calls come into genserver while the queue is being processed?  Since I return a new empty queue to handle_info {:noreply, :queue.new} will that write over items that were being added while I was processing the queue?  Or will the genserver casts be themselfs queued up then allowed to finish once handle_info is done?
Basically I am concerned about missing items during handle_info.

Code:

```
    defmodule TcpClient.Queue do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  def start_link do
    queue = :queue.new()
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, queue, name: {:global, :tcp_queue})
  end

  def init(queue) do
    Logger.debug("Starting up Queue")
    schedule_work()
    {:ok, queue}
  end

  def enqueue(msg) do
    Logger.debug("Item Added")
    GenServer.cast(whereis(), {:enqueue, msg})
  end

  defp schedule_work() do
    Process.send_after(self(), :work, 1 * 1 * 300)
  end

  def handle_cast({:enqueue, msg}, state) do
    {:noreply, :queue.in(msg, state)}
  end

  def handle_info(:work, queue) do
    case :queue.is_empty(queue) do
      true ->
        Logger.debug("No items to Process")
        nil

      false ->
        Logger.debug("Processing Queue")

        :queue.to_list(queue)
        |> Enum.map(&TcpClient.Repo.add_message(&1))

        queue = :queue.new()
    end

    schedule_work()
    {:noreply, queue}
  end

  def whereis() do
    :global.whereis_name(:tcp_queue)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Incoming messages are being put into process mailbox and *are not processed* until the process has returned from previous `handle_***`. You are risking to overflow your process’ mailbox, not to miss some messages.

To prevent this, [`GenStage`](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage) was explicitly created by Elixir Core team to fight back pressure.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa I just started looking into GenStage for the purpose of dealing with back pressure. Thanks so much for your input.